# CodeIgniter paths messing up CSS background-image directive

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

So, I am working on a website with backend for two customers. Both will have different URLs. I had a problem with Javascript links (ajax calls using url:) but that was solved using a global :

```
var SiteURL='<?php echo base_url();?>';
```

and append it to calls as necessary. The problem is when my paths go deeper e.g. website.com/book/sheet/2

the relative links would continue from 2/

While I am done with the JS, I am really lost on the CSS. I don't want to give absolute path, e.g. for background-image:url() as it will change with new customers.

Any way I can make use of base_url() or any other function?

Comment: Really hard to comment without some idea of your files layout.

Comment: Oh sorry. Here is my file structure


Root
 -- assets
     -- CSS files
     -- images -->this is where images are

 -- application folder
 -- system folder
 -- index.php, .htaccess

The problem is now as the URL goes deeper, the CSS links get broken. For .e.g they work fine for website.com. But for website.com/booking/2, any CSS rule using URL simply breaks down.

Comment: I often use that same file layout. My css links are `<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<?= base_url('assets/css/file.css');?>>` and all css url defines are relative to the css folder. ie `background-image: url("images/btn_right_large.png");` I'm not having any issue no matter how deeply the controller may be buried.

Comment: When you say "`Both will have different URLs`", do you mean different domain names or different paths but the same domain name?

Answer (score 0):

@DFriend: that somehow failed for mine as it looked for images folder in css...Firebug showed "http://localhost/samplestud/assets/**css**/images/listicons/arrow_double.png"

Simple "../images" seems to have fixed it pretty well. Thanks fellas.